# What is the Perl syntax to remove extraneous spaces from a Perl heredoc in 'use constant'?

Tags: perl, replace, constants, heredoc

I have the following structure through various pieces of code in my code base.  The use of the heredoc is good for myself and others to be able to understand the code, but it provides unnecessary bulk for transferring the data over a network to the database.

```
use constant FIND_OBJECTS_SQL => <<'    END_SQL';
    select object_name
          ,object_type
          ,0 PAC_REF
          ,owner
    from   all_objects
    where  (object_name like upper(:1)
         or object_name = upper(:1))
    and    object_type not in ('SYNONYM'
                              ,'PACKAGE BODY')
END_SQL

$object_data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(FIND_OBJECTS_SQL, $object_name);
```

What is the syntax to apply the "s/\s+/ /g" search and replace operator to the assignment?

The following two attempts do not work.

```
use constant FIND_OBJECTS_SQL => s/\s+/ /g <<'    END_SQL';
```

produces

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at U:\junk.pl line 5.
Argument "    END_SQL" isn't numeric in left bitshift (<<) at U:\junk.pl line 5.
```

and

```
use constant FIND_OBJECTS_SQL => <<'    END_SQL' =~ s/\s+/ /g;
```

produces

```
Can't modify constant item in substitution (s///) at U:\junk.pl line 15, near "s/\s+/ /g;"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example that will strip the leading whitespace from each line of a heredoc before assigning it to a constant:

```
use constant FOO => <<'STRING' =~ s/^\s+//mgr;
    abcde
    fghij
STRING

print FOO, "\n";
```

The `/r` modifier was new in Perl 5.14, and signifies that the target string isn't modified, but instead that it's copied internally, the copy is modified, and returned as the return value of the substitution operator.  For example:

```
my $new_string = $string =~ s/foo/bar/r;
```

`$new_string` would contain the modified string, and `$string` would be left alone.

Applying this to your code, it might look like this:

```
use constant FIND_OBJECTS_SQL => <<'    END_SQL' =~ s/\s+/ /gr;
    ...
    END_SQL
```

This is very similar to the last example you demonstrated, but adds the `/r` modifier so that the substitution has a useful return value, and so that it doesn't attempt to modify the HERE-doc's string literal.

Comment: The `/r` option wasn't added until [5.14.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions).

Comment: You can use [Syntax::Construct](http://p3rl.org/Syntax::Construct) if you don't remember the version for each new non-[feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html) feature.

Answer (score 4):

`s///r` returns a modified string instead of modifying the string being matched.

```
use constant CONSTANT => <<'EOI' =~ s/\s+/ /gr;
...
EOI
```

`s///r` has been available since 5.14. If you need to support older versions of Perl, you could use

```
use constant CONSTANT => do { ( my $s = <<'EOI' ) =~ s/\s+/ /g; $s };
...
EOI
```